# Spring Framework fails on paths with Windows Drive Letters

Tags: java, spring, windows, path, drive-letter

I am using Spring Framework version
4.3.18.RELEASE under Intellij on Windows 7.
I am looking at the decompiled code of, for example, the class

```
org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader
```

and the method

```
public Resource getResource(String location).
```

In that code it has a test for

```
location.startsWith("/")
```

This fails when the location is an
absolute Windows path with a leading drive letter. E.g.

```
d:/git/thredds/dap4/d4tests/src/test/resources/
```

Is there a known alternate specification of such a path that will work?

Comment: did you try something like getResource("file:d:\\git\thredds\blah.txt")

Comment: That seems to work, thanks.

Comment: For a resource file defined this way:

`file:///data/resources/file.txt`

the following path is used in windows:

`c:\data\resources\file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
 getResource("file:d:\\git\thredds\blah.txt")
```

in case the file is stored along your classes

```
getResource("classpath:com/my/package/testing.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with double slash and reverse slash? Like

```
C:\\Users\\...
```

or

```
C:\Users\...
```